# How can I assign a task/send an email to a user based on a variable in a different list?

Tags: designer-workflow, approval-process, workflow-variable, task-assignment

I have a data list for all my SP users (custom list, not the user info list).

There is an added column (look-up field) for their manager, so each user has a direct manager tagged on their 'item' entry.

I also have an InfoPath form for certain requests (ie. travel requests).

How can I assign a task/send an email to the manager of the person who created the request using the user information list and my custom list that includes the manager name/look-up field?

We have about 300 users and managers vary based on location, department, etc. Would love some best practice ideas to help map this workflow out!  Should I look at using the Workflow output variable or similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is related to the value of manager name at the user information list especially if you saved the manager name as display name , and you did not have email column .

In this case, you can use `people and group field` at your custom field instead of this lookup field of user information list.

or if you store email of the manager in user information list. you can get it in a workflow as the following

- add action to send emails.
- click on these users.
- click on to.
- select workflow lookup for use.
- add .
- at lookup for a person or group ,
- select data source user information list.
- the field from source is the email.
- and at find fields select the manager name at user information list .

[image]

- click at function button and select current item > select the manager name lookup field (in my case is Title) at your custom field.

[image]